# Why does ruby Net::HTTP lib not support multipart/form-data?

Tags: ruby, http

As ruby doc says:

> At this time Net::HTTP does not support `multipart/form-data`. To send `multipart/form-data` use `Net::HTTPRequest#body=` and `Net::HTTPRequest#content_type=:`

while it is easy to support.

I don't know why or based on what was considered that ruby `Net::HTTP` lib does not support `multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 0):

Who knows..

However, I did find [this issue](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4142) about `multipart/form-data`.

The `set_form` feature implemented in that issue is [documented here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-set_form).

Is that what you need?